# Simple find command will not run

Tags: shell, find

I am fairly new to linux and I am currently trying to run the following command,

```
find ~ -name apt.no
```

I'm looking for `apt.no` within another directory listed as `montrose-files`.

There is no response from the shell and it just creates a new line. Could anyone please explain to me why this does not produce even a result?

```
bbcharlieca@myvm:~$ find ~ -name apt.no
bbcharlieca@myvm:~$ █
```

[image]

Comment: Why should it produce a result? Do you have a file named `apt.no` somewhere in your home directory?

Comment: This means `apt.no` is not found.

Comment: I'm looking for apt.no within another directory listed as "montrose-files"

Comment: Welcome to the site. What do you mean if you say the directory is "listed as `montrose-files`". Do you mean there is a subdirectory inside your home directory called `montrose-files` where this file is to be found? If not, where is that directory?

Comment: That is correct. montrose-files is a subdirectory and I need to find a file within this subdirectory with the name as apt. no.

Comment: Apologies everyone, I just figured out that I needed to use grep to find the text within the file. But now I'm having a new issue of "Permission Denied".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command `find ~ -name apt.no` looks for a file or directory<sup>*</sup>
called `apt.no` in your `$HOME` directory and within any directories underneath it. (The `~` represents your own home directory.)

Unless `montrose-files` is within your own home directory it won't be searched, and the target file won't be found. For example, if `montrose-files` is under another path, you'd need to specify that path:

```
find /path/to/montrose-files -name 'apt.no' -print
```

Confusingly, if you have previously created a symbolic link to `montrose-files` in your home directory that also won't be searched, as `find` by default does not follow symbolic links. You can address that in one of two ways:

```
find ~ -follow -name 'apt.no' -print
find ~/montrose-files/ -name 'apt.no' -print
```

In the first approach we tell `find` to `follow` symbolic links. With some versions of `find` this can be a poor approach, because if a symbolic link points around in a loop you could end up traversing the structure several times.

In the second approach we force the symbolic link to resolve to a real directory target by appending a trailing slash.

Finally, notice that in all cases I've quoted the filename for which I'm searching. In your simple case it won't make any difference, but when you start using wildcards to match unknown parts of filenames (for example, `apt.*`) you should use the single quotes to ensure the wildcards are not processed by the shell before `find` can get hold of them). It's a good idea to get in the habit of quoting arguments.

---

<sup>* Technically, it will match any item at all, but you're unlikely to have pipes, sockets, or device nodes in your home directory</sup>